# Using .append() with lists places text on a newline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create an unordered list in javascript.  My code reads:

```
$(div).append("<ul>")
for (i in usersLst){
    $(div).append("<li>")
    $(div).append(usersLst[i][1])
    $(div).append("</li>")
}
$(div).append("</ul>")
```

Then the result is:

```
•
bob
•
alice
•
fred
```

However, if the code reads:

```
$(div).append("<ul>")
for (i in usersLst){
    $(div).append("<li>"+usersLst[i][1]+"</li>")
}
$(div).append("</ul>")
```

Then the result is:

```
 - bob
 - alice
 - fred
```

So with three separate appends it appears that a newline is being mysteriously inserted.  What's going on?

Comment: Suggest you create a jsFiddle that illustrates the issue.  http://jsFiddle.net

Comment: `.append` works on elements, not on strings. Please read the documentation

Comment: You should learn what the DOM is *before* using jQuery. It doesn't help that jQuery's API can trick you into thinking the DOM is a string. It's not.

Comment: @FelixKling `.append()` takes HTML strings, no?

Comment: @David: Well yes, but those strings are converted to elements... multiple calls to `.append` are not concatenated to one HTML string. That's what I meant...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume this code:

```
$('div')
    .append("<ul>")
    .append("<li>");
    .append('foo');
    .append("</li>")
    .append("</ul>")​​​
```

Lets have a look at the resulting structure (Chrome 21):

```
<div>
    <ul></ul>
    <li></li>
    foo
</div>
```

What happend? `.append` takes each argument and converts the strings to proper DOM elements. Thus the code is the same as doing:

```
$('div')
   .append(document.createElement('ul'))
   .append(document.createElement('li'));
   .append(document.createTextNode('foo'));
```

The two calls containing closing tags are ignored since they cannot be convert to valid HTML / DOM elements.

`.append` (and all other DOM manipulation methods) is working on **DOM elements**. It's just jQuery's way of calling [`.appendChild` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild).

HTML is just a specific format of *representing* structure. In there, each element is represented by a *opening tag* and an (optional) *closing tag*. The browser is parsing the HTML and creates the DOM in memory. The DOM (Document Object Model) is a well defined interface for interacting with hierarchical, structured data. Once you are working with the DOM, start and end tags don't exist anymore (that's HTML), only [Nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node). I recommend to read about [DOM on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM).

jQuery allows you to pass HTML strings to `.append` because it is convient, but each string is immediately converted to corresponding DOM nodes and appended to other nodes. You cannot build an HTML string with multiple calls to `.append`.

This is a corrected version of your code:

```
// jQuery parses the HTML string and creates a UL element
var $ul = $('<ul />');
// equivalent to
// var $ul = document.createElement('ul'); <- NOTE: not HTML, it's a node name

for (var i in usersLst) {
    // jQuery parses the HTML, creates a LI element and appends it to the list
    $ul.append('<li>' + usersLst[i][1] + '</li>');
    // equivalent to
    // var li = document.createElement('li');
    // li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(usersLst[i][1]));
    // $ul.appendChild(li);
}

// append the populated UL element to an existing node:
$(div).append($ul);
// equivalent to
// existingElement.appendChild($ul);
```

Comment: So are you saying that the two closing tags in the resulting HTML are created automatically?  They're not there because of the `.append("</li>"`) and `.append("<\ul>")`.  That's a little confusing.

Comment: +1 for giving append examples that don't borrow markup syntax. @J-bob: There are no tags in a DOM. It's a DOM, not HTML markup.

Comment: @J-bob: I added some more explanation, I hope it helps. Definitely read up on HTML and DOM.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for that detailed explanation.  I really appreciate it, it clears things up a lot.

Answer (score 1):

They are both incorrect. You should create the entire string first, then append it to the DIV:

```
var ul = '<ul>';
for (i in usersLst){
    ul+='<li>' + usersLst[i][1] + '</li>';
}
ul+='</ul>';

$(div).append(ul)
```