# append() and appendTo() aren't injected at end of element

Tags: jquery, dom

See http://jsfiddle.net/PAWAS/3/

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.each($(".item"), function(index, value) { 
        thisEl = $(this);
        thisEl.children("strong").after("<span style='display:inline-block'>");
        $("</span>").appendTo(thisEl);

    });
});​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
    <strong>Time Cond:</strong>
    MorningCheck
</div>​
```

Should be:

```
<div class="item">
    <strong>Time Cond:</strong>
   <span> MorningCheck</span>
</div>​
```

But the `</span>` gets injected before the text `MorningCheck`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.append` and `.appendTo` manipulate the DOM, the don't create HTML strings. Have a look at a similar question and my answer here: [Using .append() with lists places text on a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959948/using-append-with-lists-places-text-on-a-newline).

Assuming there is always only one (non-empty) text node inside the element, you can use the following to put it inside a `span` element:

```
$(".item").each(function() {
    // get all child nodes, including text nodes
    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        // is text node and does not only contain white space characters
        return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '';
    }).wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>'); // wrap in span
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DyysX/)

This looks for non-empty text nodes and wraps them inside a `span` element. If there are multiple text nodes, you might only want to get the `.last()` of them, or if you want to target the text node after the `strong` element in particular, you could do:

```
$($(this).children('strong').get(0).nextSibling).wrap(...);
```